# Is there a way to change the server location hosting map data using Google Earth API without being a Google Earth EC (Enterprise Client) customer?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I wrote a small Google Earth web application and need to be able to point to a local server's Google Earth map data - is there a way to do this or must I be a Google Earth EC (Enterprise Client) customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Your client can download the Google Earth Enterprise Plugin, or the Google Earth Enterprise Fat Client, from their support portal.